# String format work in local not in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I was format the string like this '212,121'. It's perfectly work with the below code in local machine. But its doesn't work on server. Please help me to fix this error...

This is my format :

```
         <%#Eval("balance","{0:###,###,0}") %>
```

Its working fine in local not in server...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What does happen?

Comment: do you have same regional settings on server and local machine?

Comment: Please provide more information>  "doesn't work" will not help identify the problem.  Is is displaying the value, but not formatted?  Or is it not displaying anything?

Comment: How is it "not working"? Are you getting an error? Is nothing displaying? More information would be useful. Is your server code pointed at the same DB as your local? Has the application been deployed? Did you deploy the DLL as well as the aspx?

Comment: Its showing like this '212,121'  in local but in server '2,12,121'. I need this format only '212,121'. Please fix this error..

Answer (score 6):

Check that the regional settings are the same on both.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like this? (note: untested code)

```
  <%#String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:###,###,0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "balance").ToString)%>
```